# Event get value in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, events, wxpython

I have a problem with using wxpython. I try to get a value from a column and I want to output to another column too after I hit a button. However, I dont know what I code to add to make this work.

My current code is like this:

```
import wx

class scarlett(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(400, 350))

    panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(4, 4)

    text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Scarlett')
    sizer.Add(text1, (0, 0), flag = wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
    tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1)
    sizer.Add(tc, (1, 0), (1, 6), wx.EXPAND |wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)

    text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'You')
    sizer.Add(text2, (2, 0), flag = wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border = 5 )
    list = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, style = wx.LB_ALWAYS_SB)
    sizer.Add(list, (3, 0), (3, 6), wx.EXPAND |wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)

    buttonOk = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Ok', size=(90, 28))
    buttonCancel = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Cancel', size=(90, 28))
    sizer.Add(buttonOk, (7, 1))
    sizer.Add(buttonCancel, (7, 2), flag = wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM, border = 5)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit, id=buttonCancel.GetId())

    sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
    sizer.AddGrowableRow(5)
    sizer.AddGrowableRow(6)
    sizer.SetEmptyCellSize((1, 1))
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    self.Center()
    self.Show(True)

  def OnQuit(self, event):
    self.Close()


app = wx.App()
scarlett(None, -1, 'scarlett')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I've tried to clear up your English explanation a bit (consider using a spell/grammar checker if it's not your native language). I've also removed any fluff, particularly about being a beginner (SO is for all levels of experience, as long as you try to solve your problem first, and share your findings). Please consider updating your title, trimming the code down to only essentials, and adding anything you've tried to fix this yourself. GL!

Comment: Thank you very much, im sory if my english so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting to copy text from the text control to the list box?  If that is correct then you simply need to save a reference to the controls so you can access them later in the event handler functions.  For example:

```
import wx

class scarlett(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(400, 350))

    panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(4, 4)

    text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'Scarlett')
    sizer.Add(text1, (0, 0), flag = wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
    self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1)
    sizer.Add(self.tc, (1, 0), (1, 6), wx.EXPAND |wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)

    text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, 'You')
    sizer.Add(text2, (2, 0), flag = wx.TOP | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border = 5 )
    self.listbox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, style = wx.LB_ALWAYS_SB)
    sizer.Add(self.listbox, (3, 0), (3, 6), wx.EXPAND |wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)

    buttonOk = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Ok', size=(90, 28))
    buttonCancel = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Cancel', size=(90, 28))
    sizer.Add(buttonOk, (7, 1))
    sizer.Add(buttonCancel, (7, 2), flag = wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM, border = 5)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit, buttonCancel)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCopyText, buttonOk)

    sizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
    sizer.AddGrowableRow(5)
    sizer.AddGrowableRow(6)
    sizer.SetEmptyCellSize((1, 1))
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    self.Center()
    self.Show(True)

  def OnQuit(self, event):
    self.Close()

  def OnCopyText(self, event):
    self.listbox.Append(self.tc.GetValue())

app = wx.App()
frm = scarlett(None, -1, "scarlett")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: yap, that's what i mean. its working now. Thank you very much Mr. Robin